# Symfony create button to change value

Tags: php, symfony

Since I am new at programming, I have a question. Can you program symfony in a way where you can press a button to change the value from active to non-active?

I need a button to change the status from "Actief" to "Non-actief" instead of the button "Verwijderen". 
I would appreciate some help!
Artikel.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 //link naar tabel
 /**
 * Artikel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="artikel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArtikelRepository")
 */
class Artikel
{
 //class artikel met alle items die in de tabel staan.
//per items staat aangegeven wat voor type het is en aanvullende gegevens.
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Artikelnummer", type="integer", unique=true)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $artikelnummer;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Omschrijving", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $omschrijving;

/**
* @var string
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy="artikelen")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

 private $categorie;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Technischespecificaties", type="string", length=255 , nullable=true)
 */
private $technischespecificaties;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Status", type="string", length=12, nullable=false)
 */
private $status;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="magazijnlocatie", type="string", length=6, nullable=false) 
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 6,
 *      max = 6,
 *      exactMessage = "Invoerwaarde te lang")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^20|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][0]{1}[0-9]{1}|10$/i",
 *    match=true,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR1]")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^[2]{1}[1-9]{1}\/[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR2]")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^[3-9]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][0-9]{1}$/i",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR3]")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][1]{1}[1-9]{1}$/i",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR4]")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}\/[A-Z][2-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/i",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR5]")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *    pattern = "/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/i",
 *    match=false,
 *    message="Ongeldige locatie [ERROR6]")
 */
private $magazijnlocatie;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Inkoopprijs", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
 */
private $inkoopprijs;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CodeVervangendArtikel", type="integer")
 */
private $CodeVervangendArtikel;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="MinimumVoorraad", type="string")
 */
private $minimumVoorraad;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="VoorraadInAantal", type="integer")
 */
private $voorraadInAantal;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Bestelserie", type="integer")
 */
private $bestelserie;



//set en gets van de items
/**
 * Set artikelnummer
 *
 * @param integer $artikelnummer
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setArtikelnummer($artikelnummer)
{
    $this->artikelnummer = $artikelnummer;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get artikelnummer
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getArtikelnummer()
{
    return $this->artikelnummer;
}

/**
 * Set categorie
 *
 * @param string $categorie
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setCategorie($categorie)
{
    $this->categorie = $categorie;

    return $this;
}
public function __toString()
 {     return $this->categorie; }
/**
 * Get categorie
 *
 * @return string
 */


 public function getCategorie()
{
    return $this->categorie;
}

/**
 * Set omschrijving
 *
 * @param string $omschrijving
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setOmschrijving($omschrijving)
{
    $this->omschrijving = $omschrijving;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get omschrijving
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getOmschrijving()
{
    return $this->omschrijving;
}

/**
 * Set technischespecificaties
 *
 * @param string $technischespecificaties
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setTechnischespecificaties($technischespecificaties)
{
    $this->technischespecificaties = $technischespecificaties;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get technischespecificaties
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTechnischespecificaties()
{
    return $this->technischespecificaties;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param string $status
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set magazijnlocatie
 *
 * @param string $magazijnlocatie
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setMagazijnlocatie($magazijnlocatie)
{
    $this->magazijnlocatie = $magazijnlocatie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get magazijnlocatie
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMagazijnlocatie()
{
    return $this->magazijnlocatie;
}

/**
 * Set inkoopprijs
 *
 * @param integer $inkoopprijs
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setInkoopprijs($inkoopprijs)
{
    $this->inkoopprijs = $inkoopprijs;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get inkoopprijs
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getInkoopprijs()
{
    return $this->inkoopprijs;
}

/**
 * Set CodeVervangendArtikel
 *
 * @param string $CodeVervangendArtikel
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setCodeVervangendArtikel($CodeVervangendArtikel)
{
    $this->CodeVervangendArtikel = $CodeVervangendArtikel;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get CodeVervangendArtikel
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodeVervangendArtikel()
{
    return $this->CodeVervangendArtikel;
}

/**
 * Set minimumVoorraad
 *
 * @param string $minimumVoorraad
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setMinimumVoorraad($minimumVoorraad)
{
    $this->minimumVoorraad = $minimumVoorraad;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get minimumVoorraad
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMinimumVoorraad()
{
     return $this->minimumVoorraad;
}

/**
 * Set voorraadInAantal
 *
 * @param string $voorraadInAantal
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setVoorraadInAantal($voorraadInAantal)
{
    $this->voorraadInAantal = $voorraadInAantal;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get voorraadInAantal
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getVoorraadInAantal()
{
    return $this->voorraadInAantal;
}

/**
 * Set bestelserie
 *
 * @param string $bestelserie
 *
 * @return Artikel
 */
public function setBestelserie($bestelserie)
{
    $this->bestelserie = $bestelserie;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get bestelserie
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBestelserie()
{
    return $this->bestelserie;
}
}
```

ArtikelController.php

```
<?php
//Namespace en uses, mag je vergeten. Moet er wel in staan!
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


//use van de entiteiten 
use AppBundle\Entity\Artikel;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\Artikel0Type;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\ArtikelType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Categorie;


class ArtikelController extends Controller
{


/**
* @Route("/artikel/alle", name="alleartikelen")
*/

Public function alleArtikelen(Request $request) {
    $artikelen = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Artikel")->findAll();
    return new Response($this->render('artikel.html.twig', array('artikelen' => $artikelen)));

}


/**
         * @Route("/artikel/nieuw", name="nieuwartikel")
         */
        public function nieuwArtikel(Request $request) {
            $nieuwArtikel = new Artikel();
            $form = $this->createForm(ArtikelType::class, $nieuwArtikel);

            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($nieuwArtikel);
                $em->flush() ;
                return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("alleartikelen")) ;
            }
                return new Response($this->render('form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView())));
        }

        /**
                 * @Route("/artikel/wijzig/{artikelnummer}", name="artikelwijzigen")
                 */
                public function wijzigArtikel(Request $request, $artikelnummer) {

                    $bestaandArtikel = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Artikel")->find($artikelnummer);
                    $form = $this->createForm(Artikel0Type::class, $bestaandArtikel);

                    $form->handleRequest($request);
                    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $em->persist($bestaandArtikel);
                        $em->flush() ;
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("alleartikelen", array("artikelnummer"=>$bestaandArtikel->getArtikelnummer()))) ;
                    }
                    return new Response($this->render('form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView())));
                }

                /**
                         * @Route("/artikel/verwijder/{artikelnummer}", name="artikelverwijderen")
                         */
                        public function verwijderArtikel(Request $request, $artikelnummer) {
                                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                                $bestaandArtikel = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Artikel")->find($artikelnummer);
                                $em->remove($bestaandArtikel);
                                $em->flush() ;
                                return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("alleartikelen"));
                            }





}
```

The Twig I use

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Overzicht Artikelen</h1>
<h2><a href="{{ path('nieuwartikel',{}) }}">Nieuw Artikel</a></h2>
<ol>
{% for artikel in artikelen %}
        <li style="color:darkgreen">
            Artikelnummer: {{artikel.artikelnummer}} <br>
            Omschrijving: {{artikel.omschrijving}} <br>
            Technischespecificaties: {{artikel.technischespecificaties}} <br>
            Categorie: {{artikel.categorie}} <br>
            Magazijnlocatie: {{artikel.magazijnlocatie}} <br>
            Inkoopprijs: {{artikel.inkoopprijs}} <br>
            CodeVervangendArtikel: {{artikel.CodeVervangendArtikel}} <br>
            MinimumVoorraad: {{artikel.minimumVoorraad}} <br>
            VoorraadInAantal: {{artikel.voorraadInAantal}} <br>
            Bestelserie: {{artikel.bestelserie}} <br>

            <a href="{{ path('artikelwijzigen',{'artikelnummer':artikel.artikelnummer}) }}">Wijzig</a>
            <a href="{{ path('artikelverwijderen',{'artikelnummer':artikel.artikelnummer}) }}">Verwijder</a>
    </li><br>
{% endfor %}
<ol>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I have no clue where to begin

Comment: `<a href="{{ path('artikelactivare',{'artikelnummer':artikel.artikelnummer}) }}">Activate</a> <a href="{{ path('artikeldesactivate',{'artikelnummer':artikel.artikelnummer}) }}">Activate</a>`  in the new action get the object like the other method and call `setActivate(true)` ou false ...

Comment: the  think I have found so far is that I should edit the edit controller "verwijder" function to get persist.

Comment: Yes, good luck.

Comment: Did you see my answer @Colin?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's a good idea NOT to post all of your code, but only post the "relevant" code. Most people on SO are busy and don't have to go through all your code. It's best to have minimal code.

Secondly, i think you mean you want to set an Article's `status` to inactive. I think that is correct? It's not very clear from your post. That is the second point to make your post very clear so people can help you better.

Give that, you probably want to render a Twig template that has a URL to will redirect to a controller that handles the inactivation of the article. So let's call that route `/articleInactivate/{artID}`. If you are using routing annotation, that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/articleInactivate/{artID}",
 * defaults={"artID" = 0},
 * name="articleInactivate")
 */
public function articleInactivateAction($artID, Request $request){
    ...
```

Then what you could do is in the `articleInactivate` controller, query for the passed in parameter of the `artID` like so:

```
$Artikel = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Artikel")->find($artID);
```

Then set the status:

```
$Artikel->setStatus('inactive');
```

Then persist and flush:

```
$em->persist( $Artikel );
$em->flush();
```

To get to the controller from Twig, you need a URL with the route and the parameters:

```
<a href="{{ path('articleInactivate', {'artID':artikel.artikelnummer}) }}">Inactivate Article</a>
```

You can take a look at my article on something similar to that here:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/specify-route-with-parameters-in-twig/

Hopefully that helps you!